# How to debug Android Bluetooth issue?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an Android App. The app is used to control a device via bluebooth.

Now I'm facing an issue that, on some Phone like Huawei, my app works very stable with the device, but on some Xiaomi models, my app doesn't work well, for example bluebooth connection hard to establish, or connection frequently drops.

I know this question is hard to answer. I just wonder if anybody has similar experience? And if anybody can provide some idea on how to debug this issue.